# Integrate SonarQube with AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to integrate `SonarQube` with `AWS CodeBuild`?

Since I cannot install any plugins on `AWS CodeBuild`, I would like some advice on how to achieve this.

------EDIT--------

I think I can use https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

Answer (score 3):

I recently integrated SonarQube with Codebuild - 
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codebuild-samples/blob/master/buildspecs/sonarqube.yml

This buildspec file gets you started. Dont forget to copy your sonar scanner properties to /sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-linux/bin/

Comment: Yup. Did that 6 months back.